# C++ program changing behavior with different Compiler

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, glm-math, glew

I have a problem, where my program is changing it's behavior, based upon if it was started from a debugger. THE BINARY IS THE SAME! My issue is starting the program in those following two ways:

`gdb game` vs `game` (game is the executabale. or game.exe if you are on windows)

If there is a debugger attached, my program works as intended. You should see a Square in the middle of the Window, that will open. When you go an move the Square (wasd/arrow keys), you see, that there are actually two squares stacked ontop of each other.
[image: Image showing the intended result]

When the program is launched without a debugger, the second "stationary" square is not there.
[image: Image showing, what the Programm shouldn't do]

Program code: https://github.com/C0D3-M4513R/OpenGLGame/tree/development

The issue is, that under Shader.cpp in the applyMVP call, the provided Matrix its contents changes, from c++ (right before the method call to OpenGL) to OpenGL (the method call, that changes the OpenGL state)

```cpp
void Shader::applyMVP(glm::mat4 model) const {
    //TODO::Projection Matrix
//    glm::mat4 mvp = Renderer::getCamera()->view() * model;
    glm::mat4 mvp = model;
    const float* mvpPointer = glm::value_ptr(mvp);

#ifndef DEBUG
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        SDL_LogVerbose(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_SYSTEM,"MVP Matrix[%u]: %f",i,mvpPointer[i]);
    }
#endif


    glUseProgram(program);
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvp");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, mvpPointer);

    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

In my code everything is fine, but in OpenGL the `glUniformMatrix4fv()` call suddenly has very wierd values. Values, that I never supplied!

If you want to compile this project for yourself, you need the following:

- SDL2 libraries and headers
- GLEW libraries and headers
- A (working) cmake environment

If you are running Linux or Windows doesn't matter, as the program and the compiling works on both.

EDIT:
On Windows(with MINGW) the Problem is exactly as described, but on Linux (with GCC) everything works. So I am guessing, that MINGW is the issue?

I am marking the Question complete, once the problem has been resolved with MINGW.

Comment: Normally this means you have UB somewhere. Make sure you have warnings enabled and don't get any, try running with address&UB sanitizers, try `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, try valgrind, etc.

Comment: I am compiling with the flag -Wall. The only warnings I get are -Wreorder warnings.

Comment: I'd add `-Wextra` as well.

Comment: With -Wextra and -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG I get additionally the following types: -Wignored-qualifiers and -Wunused-parameter (that only on main). But the issue persists.
I am setting the Flags via CMake. Am I doing that correctly?
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG")`

Comment: @C0D3M4513R -Wall can't tell you about every kind of UB. The problem you're describing reeks of a pointer aliasing issue. I presume you're working on a x86 CPU, so memory access ordering issues shouldn't creep up. Anyway, somewhere between getting the pointer and submitting it to OpenGL "something" happens. It's almost as if `mvp` went out of scope (which it doesn't).

Comment: @C0D3M4513R *"Am I doing that correctly?"* Yep. If it didn't help, enable the sanitizers, or look the for the UB maunaly.

Comment: Be aware of [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). If you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Read more documentation

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I would love to read Documentation, but which one(s)?

Comment: You should read: [This C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp),  a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), the documentation of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), the documentation of [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), the source code and documentation of [Qt](http://qt.io)

Comment: ... the source code and documentation of [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), the documentation of your source code editor (perhaps [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...), the documentation of [MinGW64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), the documentation of [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), [*what every C  programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: If your GCC is recent enough, you can enable some checks with `-fanalyzer`. You could also use clang with `-fsanitize=address`.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine GCC has `-fsanitize=address` as well.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine This the issue is not some wrong address-handling. Everything is valid c++ code. It's the Compiler. And I will have to debug the MINGW compile, as it is having trouble with my code. Some GCC flag doesn't help me. Oh and I checked with that flag and Valgrind. I do have memory leaks in my binary, but not in my own code (They are in nvidia (Not even code on the callstack is mine there) and glfw(Init) code).

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `glm::mat4x4 rotation;` in the class `Face` is not initialized.

The [glm API documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) refers to [The OpenGL Shading Language specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#constructors).

> 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors
>
> If there is a single scalar parameter to a vector constructor, it is used to initialize all components of the constructed vector to that scalar’s value. If there is a single scalar parameter to a matrix constructor, it is used to initialize all the components on the matrix’s diagonal, with the remaining components initialized to 0.0.

This means, that an identity matrix can be initialized by the single parameter 1.0:

```cpp
glm::mat4 rotation = glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. I fixed a bunch of those things, but that isn't important, since I am not actually using the rotation variable(reading) at the moment.
And also it may be, that you can initialize a matrix, like you described, but in my context (a header file) that wouldn't work, since that would declare a function.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes different compilers do behave differently. Be sure to try an alternative IDE to investigate if the issue still exists.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, but now I'm baffled. Before I was compiling with MINGW on Windows. I now tried it with GCC under Linux and everything just works. What are the differences, that I should be aware of in this case? Or is it just some quirk, that I have to deal with? And If that is the case, how do I deal with that quirk to make sure, that I can support as many platforms as possible?

Comment: Windows and Linux are *very different* operating systems, and you need to read the documentation of each of them. Of course, read also [a textbook about operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)